# hello, I'm new using PHP Framework, I got a problem with Laravel PHP artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-serve

I'm new using PHP Framework, I got a problem with Laravel PHP artisan serve

```sh
php artisan serve
```

> PHP Warning:  require(D:\LARAVEL\Login\login3-app/vendor/autoload.php): Failed t
> o open stream: No such file or directory in D:\LARAVEL\Login\login3-app\artisan
> on line 18
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'D:\LARAVEL\Login\logi
> n3-app/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\LARAVEL\Login\l
> ogin3-app\artisan:18
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in D:\LARAVEL\Login\login3-app\artisan on line 18

Please help me

Comment: did you run `composer update`?

Comment: Run `composer install`

Comment: Mark answer accepted to let the others know which is correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `composer install` or `composer update` to install dependencies and create `vendor` folder inside your app